# Can't test class within a module in RSpec

Tags: ruby, oop, rspec, tdd, bdd

I am learning RSpec and seem to be failing miserably with any code outside of a tutorial.  Which is why I am banging my head against the wall with this problem.  Hopefully you all can help.

lib/NegotiGate

```
module NegotiGate
  class Negotiation

    def initialize(price1, price2)
      @price1 = price1
      @price2 = price2
    end

    def both_prices_equal?(price1, price2)
      if @price1 == @price2
        true
      else
        false
      end
    end

  end
end
```

spec/NegotiGate_spec.rb

```
describe NegotiGate do

  before(:each) do
    @negotiate = Negotiation.new(10,10)
  end

  describe "Negotiation" do
    describe ".both_prices_equal?" do
      context "given the sellers price is the same as the buyers highest buying price" do
        it 'returns true' do
          expect(@negotiate.both_prices_equal?).to be_true
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Output:

```
NegotiGate
  Negotiation
    .both_prices_equal?
      given the sellers price is the same as the buyers highest buying price
        returns true (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) NegotiGate Negotiation .both_prices_equal? given the sellers price is the same as the buyers highest buying price returns true
     Failure/Error: @negotiate = Negotiation.new(10,10)

     NameError:
       uninitialized constant Negotiation
     # ./spec/NegotiGate_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00134 seconds (files took 0.15852 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/NegotiGate_spec.rb:11 # NegotiGate Negotiation .both_prices_equal? given the sellers price is the same as the buyers highest buying price returns true
```

Any help is greatly appreciated from a student of TDD.
Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`describe` blocks in RSpec don't affect Ruby namespacing. In your spec, you need to refer to `Negotiation` as `NegotiGate::Negotiation` everywhere.

However, what you're really describing in that spec is not `NegotiGate` but `NegotiGate::Negotiation`, so change the `describe` block to `describe NegotiGate::Negotiation` and then you can use `described_class` for short:

```
describe NegotiGate::Negotiation do
  before(:each) do
    @negotiate = described_class.new(10,10)
  end

  describe ".both_prices_equal?" do
    context "given the sellers price is the same as the buyers highest buying price" do
      it 'returns true' do
        expect(@negotiate.both_prices_equal?).to be_true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

By the way, check out RSpec's `let`, which is the modern way to define variables used in multiple tests. Actually in what you show you should just declare a local in your example, but you'll presumably write more tests and it will then be worth defining `negotiate` once. Oh, and naming it `negotiation` to match the class name would be nicer than `negotiate`.

Comment: Thanks! I am just getting started, and testing is hard for me to wrap my head around sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Try `NegotiGate::Negotiation.new` instead.